# different aspects (linestrings) in one kml file

Tags: kml, google-earth

I want present different aspects on the same path (so different linestrings) in one kml file.
Does the KML format support hierarchical structure of objects:

```
Document
  Aspect1
    Aspect1_1
      LineString1
      LineString2
    Aspekt1_2
      LineString1
  Aspect2
  ...
Document
```

So I need to have many aspects in one file.

UPD: What about many LineStrings with different LineStyles within one Placemark?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by an aspect. However, this might be useful. Give the containing Folder or Document a ListStyle with listItemType of radioFolder:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#liststyle

Which then displays your options in the left pane as radio buttons, so only one can be selected at a time. Then create different Placemarks with a LineString displayed in some way different from the others.

Comment: Aspect=Folder (it is strange, I know).